Parse WhatsApp message read status
My question is more about html layout and parsing dynamic of content.
My task: parse contacts who read my particular message in the Group.
I tried to see DOM structure for the DIV block that hold that contacts.
But it's dynamic and list 20 items only. So when I scroll down it's updated.
So what should I do to read and parse all contacts (upto 1000 contacts)
Need some links/tutorials on how people do this type of parsing nowadays.
P.S. my WA Group is full of contacts, so I wanted to write an app to see who is not active for some long time so I can remove them and free slots for new people.
Thanks!

Doesn't WhatsApp have an API? It would probably be easier to use that instead of trying to scrape/automate their UI.

WhatsApp Web UI is not suitable for automation. It is better to use the API. Moreover, WhatsApp Web UI is changing very frequently.

You need to match the outer elements, then match their inner elements.
Your first task is gonna be to find the <div> with the info. I'm seeing a <header> that contains and <div> with front-facing @title="Message info".
Next to that <div> (i.e., a sibling at the same level), I see the <div> you want. It has @tabindex="-1". There are multiple divs with this same element, so you need to match the outer element first if you don't want false positives.
Inside of that <div> the targets have @role="listitem". Inside of that <div>, I see three interesting leaf elements: <img> with the user's pfp, a <span> with the data you want, and another <span> with a timestamp.
